# JFrog Container Registry Problems with LDAP

Tags: jfrog-container-registry

We are evaluating JFrog Container Registry.  We already use Artifactory Pro.  For evaluation, we used a vanilla installation from a ZIP on Linux that used the service install script and installation using `apt-get`.  Both have the same LDAP problem.  When configuring LDAP and saving the configuration, we get no class def found errors.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.springframework.security.ldap.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource
        at org.artifactory.security.ldap.ArtifactoryLdapAuthenticator.createSecurityContext(ArtifactoryLdapAuthenticator.java:82)
        at org.artifactory.security.ldap.ArtifactoryLdapAuthenticator.createBindAuthenticators(ArtifactoryLdapAuthenticator.java:197)
        at org.artifactory.security.ldap.ArtifactoryLdapAuthenticator.init(ArtifactoryLdapAuthenticator.java:162)
        at org.artifactory.security.ldap.ArtifactoryLdapAuthenticator.reload(ArtifactoryLdapAuthenticator.java:180)
```

This seems really weird because LDAP works fine with our Artifactory and JCR looks like it is just a stripped down version of Artifactory or Artifactory configured to only be used as an image registry.  Is anyone else experiencing teething problems with JCR?  It makes me think JCR is not ready for prime time

Answer (score 0):

LDAP is supported in JFrog Container Registry the same way it is supported with JFrog Artifactory Pro. I have just configured LDAP on JCR with no problem actually. Can you please add the entire stack trace so we can have a further look? 
You can also open a Jira ticket here: https://www.jfrog.com/jira or contact JFrog Support directly (support@jfrog.com) to get support with setting up LDAP.